# Swift регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ios, swift

Есть ли в swift регулярные выражения? Если да, то как воспользоваться? Если нет, то как парсить?

Answer (score 1):

[Есть, конечно](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html).

Регулярки с swift не встроены в язык, как в Perl, а вынесены в библиотеку.

По поводу того, чем парсить — разумеется, парсером. Регулярки далеко не всегда адекватное средство для этого.

Comment: Так и каким парсером парсить? Либо как воспользоваться регулярками?

Comment: @DeOne: Парсером той грамматики, которую вы хотите распарсить, конечно. Если вы парсите XML — то парсером XML, если JSON, то парсером JSON, ну и так далее.

Comment: @DeOne: По поводу использования, [вот вам пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25882504/276994).